# c# add button event programmatically

Tags: c#, events, web-controls

Trying to add buttons programmatically to a webform.
        Some work - others don't.
        In the code below I add btnY and btnX in the Page_Load.
        These both work - they show on the page and fire the event
        and the code in the event handler works....
        In the page load I also run bindData which gets a DataTable
        and uses the data to create controls.
        in the example I am only creating Button.
        These buttons will appear on the page correctly but when clicked 
        they only do a postback .. 
        the code in the event handler doesn't work - does it get called?
        The event handler is the same for all the buttons.
        Any ideas why or how I can make it work?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(btn("btnY", "Y"));
    Pages P = new Pages();
    bindData(P.DT);
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(btn("btnX", "X"));
}
Button btn(string id, string text)
{
    Button btn1 = new Button();
    btn1.ID = id;
    btn1.Text = text;
    btn1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btn_click);
    return btn1;
}
protected void bindData(DataTable dt)
{
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        render(Convert.ToInt32(row["PageKey"]));
    }
}
protected void render(int pageKey)
{
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(btn("btn_" + pageKey.ToString(), "Edit"));
}

protected void btn_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = (Button)sender;
    string id = btn.ID;
    Pages P = new Pages();
    bindData(P.DT);
    lt.Text = "ID=" + id;

}
```

Comment: Add an `Event Handler` for your `btn`  inside `Page_Load`

Comment: Just tried this in the page_load... still no good               foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
            {
                if (c is Button)
                {
                    Button b = (Button)c;
                    b.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btn_click);
                }
            }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind .. figured it out .. example above should work, my actual code had a if (!Page.PostBack) that caused the problem